# Neighbor dog jumping on fence

Tags: dogs

I’m not sure what to do at this point. I have neighbors that normally has 4 bloodhounds. One just recently pass away. Every time one passes away she get another one. The county I’m in you are only allowed 3 dogs. Every 2/4 weeks she will baby sit two more dogs that are bloodhounds. And sometime has friends over with bloodhounds. So the most I have seen is 8 bloodhounds on quarter acre lot. When the dogs are outside. They go nuts. Bark at everything. When me or my dogs Are outside. They always come to my fence, and run back and forward barking at us. I feel like they don’t get enough attend from the owner. So I decided to put up the strips that go into chain link fence to block their view to my yard. Well that didn’t block their total view. I then got mesh. That blocks their view but now they jump on the fence and bark and just look in our yard. I have talked to some of the other neighbors and it not just the barking and jump all over the fence, the odor that come from their yard is horrible in the summer bc they don’t clean up after the dogs. I feel like if I report them it won’t help solve anything as other neighbors have already complained to them about their dogs. What should I do? I feel like I shouldn’t have to deal with this as I can’t even enjoy my backyard with the barking

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! I understand completely that you have a problem! But for this site you need to fformulate a clear question or aim you want ro reach. We can not decide for you, if you should build a wall or call the police :) Please use the edit buttom and add such a question/aim so we can help you :) Also you can find more info about things here in your profile or at the bottom of this site at "help"

Comment: -.- please excuse my writing... freezing fingers are no help ^^

Comment: I'm afraid there's not much we can do to help you. Since these aren't your dogs, you cannot train them or anything. Your problem is not the dogs, but the people. The best you can do is record a video of the annoying behavior and send an email complaint with the video attached as evidence.